# Create new extension association and icon in SnowLeopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, icons, file-association, file-extension

I was searching for the best way to add a new file extension type (.xyz) and associate an icon to all files of that kind in SnowLeopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you want a specific application to open these file types, or leave them unassociated.

---

If you want them to open with a specific application, you select that application in one of these files' *Get Info* dialog and check *Always Open With* in the selection dialog.

Now this file extension is associated with that application, but probably has a generic icon. The icon is the associated application's responsibility, so we need to change it.

---

Now you need to edit your application's bundle:

Right-click the application to handle these file extensions and select *Show Package Contents*. Navigate to `Contents`, and edit `Info.plist`. You might need *Property List Editor*, which is part of Apple's developer tools. If you're lucky, it's an XML format. Edit this file's `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and add the following for the extension `.foo`:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <!-- keep the other entries! -->
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>foo</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>FooDocument</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Foo Document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Save the file.

---

For the icon, you need to create a file in `AppName.app/Contents/Resources/` named `FooDocument.icns`. You can create `icns` files using *Preview* or specialized utilities.

---

You will need to repeat this every time you update the application.

---

If you don't want the files to open with a specific application, you can create a new "dummy" application bundle (it doesn't even need to be able to launch), where you place the icon and add the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` information from above.

Comment: To get the changes to take effect, move the application to a different folder and back again, and relaunch it. This will update Launch Services.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be creating the dummy application and associating it with the file extension, but making it launch the real editor.

Comment: Yep, works. I'll add an explanation to my answer if you want.

Comment: I think i will stick with the dummy application because i have no need to associate file with apps. Thanks a lot for the info, Greatest. answer. ever.

What is the minimum requirements for a dummy application?
may i build one only with the `Info.plist` and the `FooDocument.icns`?

Comment: @Scakko I'm not sure. Safe bet is to launch Automator, select the *Application* template, and save. Then go crazy within that app bundle. Change the `CFBundleTypeRole` to `None` as a precaution, [otherwise your empty application might get associated with the file type](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABJHDGA).